# How to Increase SQL Query Performance on where clauses searching concatenated values

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a query that runs extremely well (fast) when run, but as soon as I try to search by a concatenated value, the performance dives.

What are my options for keeping the performance high? I'm aware that the obvious solution is to not search by a concatenated string, but there will be situations that I cannot help but do so. How do I deal with those situations.

Example 1: Runs Fast

```
Select * From
(
    With Exmp1 AS 
    (
    Select ID, RCD From Table1 a where EFFDT = (Select Max(b.EFFDT) 
    FROM Table1 b 
    Where a.ID = b.ID and a.RCD = b.RCD) and status = 'A'
    )

    Select USERNAME, RCD
    From MainTable MT Inner Join Exmp1 E1 ON MT.ID = E1.ID 

)
Where USERNAME = 'test1'
```

Example 2: Runs Slow

```
Select * From
(
    With Exmp1 AS 
    (
    Select ID, RCD From Table1 a where EFFDT = (Select Max(b.EFFDT) 
    FROM Table1 b 
    Where a.ID = b.ID and a.RCD = b.RCD) and status = 'A'
    )

    Select USERNAME || '@domain.com', RCD
    From MainTable MT Inner Join Exmp1 E1 ON MT.ID = E1.ID 

)
Where USERNAME = 'test1@domain.com'
```

If you are wondering why I have the whole query wrapped in a select, the application that consumes this query has an expectation that the query begins with 'Select'. I already tried re-writing it without the "with" clause but I get the same results.

```
Select USERNAME || '@domain.com', RCD
From MainTable MT Inner Join 
(Select ID, RCD 
 From Table1 a 
 Where EFFDT = (Select Max(b.EFFDT) FROM Table1 b Where a.ID = b.ID and a.RCD = b.RCD) and status = 'A'
) E1 ON MT.ID = E1.ID 
Where USERNAME|| '@domain.com' = 'test1@domain.com'
```

============
Edited for Additional Info:

Table1 has four columns: ID, RCD, EFFDT, STATUS. It's important that I only get the most recent records (EFFDT) and records that have status value of 'A'.

Main Table has two columns: ID, USERNAME. I am unable to change this table or create additional tables, database views. I have to use this data as it exists today and only interact in the form of SQL Queries.

The desired result is USERNAME@domain.com and RCD for a given USERNAME@domain.com.

Be mindful that this is just a specific example, and general help on the subject is appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some sample data and the desired result for them?

Comment: I'm always getting the correct data output, so I'm not as concerned about that, but if it helps, I'll update the post with some additional data.

Comment: Using a materialized view might be a good option or a generated column

Comment: Please list all the indexes `Table1` and `MainTable` have.

Comment: @TheImpaler ID (in both tables) and USERNAME have indexes.

Comment: @RaymondNijland is it possible to do so in the query? If so could you please provide an example?

Comment: are those where clauses searching concatenated values always the same? Otherwise using materialized view or a generated column also does not make much sense.. ideally see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.. Ideally we also need to have the `CREATE TABLE` statements so we know the datatypes and indexing..

Comment: @RaymondNijland  No the concatenated values will almost always be different. As TheImpaler pointed out, the issue is the SQL optimizer, and I was hoping to find some way to frame the query or give optimizer hints in order to better handle the concatenated search.

Comment: *" No the concatenated values will almost always be different. As TheImpaler pointed out, the issue is the SQL optimizer,"* No iam pretty sure @TheImpaler meant something else.. The issue is the question you ask the database to do with `USERNAME || '@domain.com'` its a fill in the blanks kind of question, which search algorithms simpley cant handle to do "fast".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you concatenate the string you are preventing the SQL optimizer to use the existing index on `MainTable (USERNAME)`. That forces the engine to follow a different [slower] path; probably a HEAP [TABLE] SCAN. As simple as that.

If you really need to provide the full email address I would compute the concatenation in the last step and not before, essentially going back to your first option. For example:

```
Select USERNAME || '@domain.com', RCD From
(
    With Exmp1 AS 
    (
    Select ID, RCD From Table1 a where EFFDT = (Select Max(b.EFFDT) 
    FROM Table1 b 
    Where a.ID = b.ID and a.RCD = b.RCD) and status = 'A'
    )

    Select USERNAME, RCD
    From MainTable MT Inner Join Exmp1 E1 ON MT.ID = E1.ID 

)
Where USERNAME = 'test1'
```

**EDIT**:

Taking the idea one step further you can rephrase the whole query and find out which optimizations are easily visible once the query is simplified:

- The thing is the column `MT.USERNAME` is probably much more selective than `a.STATUS`, so you should filter by it first.
- Then, to make the correlated subquery fast, you probably want to use a "covering index" on it, so I suggest adding `ix2` as shown below.

For example:

```
Select
  MT.USERNAME || '@domain.com', a.RCD 
From MainTable MT
join Table1 a on a.ID = MT.ID
where MT.USERNAME = 'test1'
  and a.status = 'A'
  and a.EFFDT = (
    Select Max(b.EFFDT) FROM Table1 b Where a.ID = b.ID and a.RCD = b.RCD
  )
```

Now, in order for this query to be real fast you'll need the following indexes. It seems you already have the first one:

```
create index ix1 on MainTable (USERNAME); -- You already have this one
create index ix2 on Table1 (ID, RCD, EFFDT);
```

**SECOND EDIT**: If you really want to search using the full username you can add an index on an expression. Take your "Example 2" and change the `WHERE` condition as shown below:

```
Select * From
(
    With Exmp1 AS 
    (
    Select ID, RCD From Table1 a where EFFDT = (Select Max(b.EFFDT) 
    FROM Table1 b 
    Where a.ID = b.ID and a.RCD = b.RCD) and status = 'A'
    )

    Select USERNAME || '@domain.com', RCD
    From MainTable MT Inner Join Exmp1 E1 ON MT.ID = E1.ID 

)
Where USERNAME || '@domain.com' = 'test1@domain.com' -- changed here
```

Then add the following index:

```
create index ix3 on MainTable (USERNAME || '@domain.com');
```

This should make the query fast, since the filtering preficate will be an exact match with the index.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this. I agree with everything you say here, but it unfortunately doesn't address my question. I MUST use a where clause that searches by a concatenated value. I have no options in that. Your response shows all the ways, to try and avoid doing so, which I agree is clearly optimal, but for my purposes I cannot.

Comment: @DrewAschenbrener OK, got you. You still have the option of adding an index with an expression. Let me check.

Comment: If the concatenated value is "always" different... where is it coming from?

Comment: *"If the concatenated value is "always" different."*  @DrewAschenbrener i would suggest making some kind of precalculated lookup table i don't see a other option in this case as optimizers can't handle the "unknown"..  First run slow, second run "optimized" because you can use the lookup table to join on.

Comment: The application that consumes the SQL has the ability to append to the "where clause" (the final where clause in the entire SQL) an additional parameter. That system can only give the domained username value. Hence, I get a situation where it takes my SQL and tacks on "Where x = y@domain.com"

Comment: @DrewAschenbrener If that's the case, I only see the option to materialize a view, as Raymond Nijland mentioned before.

Comment: I understand. Thank you both for you constant feedback. I know this was not a well defined problem and it's use case is inherently very strange. I will mark your answer as correct (anyone who looks at this post should follow your advice).